# Video card not working only on one computer

Tags: video, graphics-card, motherboard

I got this weird problem. My girlfriends computer suddenly just stopped displaying any picture oon the screen.
Video card is Nvidia GF9400GT, which is originally silent, but I've added one 60mm fan to it and it's all been working fine for years. Motherboard is Gigabyte GA-945PL-S3P.

So I took the card to my office and tried it in several of my computers, and amazingly, it's running normally. So then I put it in my home computer (small cube, hard to dissasemble) and there it's also working fine. Put it back in my GF's machine - nothing. Bios lets out 1 long and 2 short beeps for VGA error and that's it.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: It looks like the motherboard on your GF's computer is the problem. Have you tried any of the other PCI slots?

Comment: There's only one PCIe. I forgot to mention that two of the testing cards from work are working OK, and my GTX 780 ti is also working just fine

Comment: That is quite strange indeed. What OS is she running?

Comment: 8.1 x64 right now. OS is irrelevant here, because MB can't even pass the tests. It makes the beep error code for the bad VGA and that's it. No BIOS, no pos, nothing. I'm totally baffled

Comment: You could try resetting your BIOS: [Reset BIOS](http://www.wikihow.com/Reset-Your-BIOS)

Comment: Oh tried that. Downgraded it to some official version but then win 8.1 wasn't bootable.
For the time being,  there is no solution, it seems... 
Thanks for your time Yass

Comment: No probs. I hope you get to the bottom of it.